# TinySort sort by IDs

Tags: javascript, html, tinysort

This one is silly, but I find TinySort (standalone min) confusing to me:
I want to sort divs (.story) in a container div (#body), so I use a `<button onclick="tinysort('div#body>div,{order:'desc',attr:'id'});">Descending</button>`, that after clicking switches to Ascending. My code for divs is:

```
<div id="body">
<div id="1" class="story"></div>
<div id="2" class="story"></div>
<div id="3" class="story"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom function like so:

HTML

```
<button id='toggle' onclick='toggleSort()'>Descending</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function toggleSort() {
    var btn = document.querySelector('#toggle');
    if(btn.classList.toggle('desc')) {
        tinysort('div#body>div', { order: 'desc', attr: 'id' });
        btn.innerHTML = 'Ascending';
    } else {
        tinysort('div#body>div', { order: 'asc', attr: 'id' });
        btn.innerHTML = 'Descending';
    }
}
```

Made a demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1t1qLrL6/)

Comment: That worked. Is there any way of making a cookie out of this to remember the choice?

Comment: You could use cookies (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or local storage if it is available (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). You could store a boolean value, true for ascending and false for descending, and update it each time the function runs. On page load you could read the value then set the sort method accordingly.

Comment: I made "this", it's a mess, any help? :( https://jsfiddle.net/1of2mexo/
Since I'm doing it for Tumblr, it has a lot of other cookies from Tumblr's side, so I have to find mine

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/5w6dsoba/2/ You weren't reading the cookie correctly, it is called 'order', you were trying to look for a cookie called 'asc'. Your conditional `asccookie === 'order=asc'` is slightly wrong too, it should be `asccookie === 'asc'` as `asccookie` just holds the value of the cookie.